Number of leaves in complete binary tree
I got confused a bit about definitions and from reading in the different forums, does both complete binary tree (last level is not full) and perfect binary tree, number of leaves are ⌈n/2⌉ for a tree with n nodes ? If not for what binary tree is it true? And I am asking about the exact number and not boundary.
Thanks

A full binary tree is a binary tree where every node is either a leaf or is internal with two children.
Is such a tree has $k$ internal nodes then it has $k+1$ leaves. Thus when the total number of nodes equals $n=2k+1$ the the number of leaves equals $k+1=\lceil \frac n2\rceil$.  Whatever the structure of that tree.
This can be proved using induction.


[…] does both complete binary tree (last level is not full) and perfect binary tree, number of leaves are ⌈n/2⌉ for a tree with n nodes ?

Yes!
Every perfect binary tree is a full binary tree, so is covered by Hendrik Jan's answer.
A complete binary tree is not necessarily a full binary tree; for example, the below is a complete binary tree whose root node has exactly one child:
  A
 /
B

Nonetheless, every complete binary tree with $n$ nodes does have $\lceil \frac n 2 \rceil$ leaf nodes. To see this, observe that there are only two cases:

It is a full binary tree: each of its nodes has two children or zero children.

In this case it's covered by Hendrik Jan's answer.


Exactly one of its nodes has exactly one child.

In this case, consider the subgraph induced by removing that one child. This subgraph is a full binary tree with $n - 1$ nodes, of which (by Hendrik Jan's answer) $\frac n 2 - 1$ are internal nodes and $\frac n 2$ are leaf nodes. So the original complete binary tree (including the child) has $\frac n 2$ internal nodes and $\frac n 2$ leaf nodes.




Thanks for this addition! +1
